# Jquery .next() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Guys i am trying to do something like this
i have two href and a text  box in the middle of those
<-> TEXT <+>
So when i press the - and + the value in the txt must increase or decrease by one

```
<!-- <div class="quantity noprint">
   <div  class="subtract" title="Less Quantity"></div><input type="text" id="addToCartQty<%=addProduct.getLongID()%>" value="<%=addProduct.getInteger("ATR_WebMinQuantity",1)/addProduct.getInteger(MCRConstants.DM_ATR_LEGACY_CASE_VENDOR_PACK_SIZE,1) %>" name="ADD_CART_ITEM<>quantity" class="text" maxlength="3" /><div  class="add" title="Add Quantity"></div>

</div> --!>
```

and i am using a jquery to + and - the value in the text box. Whenever i press + its happening correctly but for - it takes the TEXT fields name instead of its value . Any solution for this to make it to take the value of the TEXT box
Jquery used follows :

```
 $(".quantity .subtract").click(function () {
        var qtyInput = $(this).next('input');
        var qty = parseInt(qtyInput.val());
        if (qty > 1)
            qtyInput.val(qty - 1);

        qtyInput.focus();
        return false;
    });

    $(".quantity .add").click(function () {
        var qtyInput = $(this).prev('input');
        var qty = parseInt(qtyInput.val());
        if (qty >= 0 && (qty + 1 <= 999))
            qtyInput.val(qty + 1);

        qtyInput.focus();
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

.next() returns the next sibling of each selected element. If a selector is passed into the function, the next sibling is returned only if it matches the selector. Since your + and - links are separate elements, they will have different next siblings. You are looking for .siblings():

```
var qtyInput = $(this).siblings('input');
```

Comment: So if i use var qtyInput = $(this).siblings('input');
and qtyInput .val() then that will give me the value of the TEXT box ? is it so

Comment: Assuming the text box is the only input element that is a sibling of your + and - elements, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the `nextAll()` function: http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try another type of query:

```
$(".quantity .subtract").click(function () {
    var qtyInput = $(this).closest('.quantity').find('input');
    var qty = parseInt(qtyInput.val());
    if (qty > 1)
        qtyInput.val(qty - 1);

    qtyInput.focus();
    return false;
});

$(".quantity .add").click(function () {
    var qtyInput = $(this).closest('.quantity').find('input');
    var qty = parseInt(qtyInput.val());
    if (qty >= 0 && (qty + 1 <= 999))
        qtyInput.val(qty + 1);

    qtyInput.focus();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/CSCcD/) works. I cleaned up some of unnecessary for this sample properties.

**UPDATE:**

Could `ADD_CART_ITEM<>quantity` be a reason for an issue? `>` can be interpreted as a closing tag and result in a strange behavior. At least, as you can see from my sample, your code should work, unless there are some hidden issues in it. The idea is definitely correct.

Comment: It cannot be interpreted as closing tag as it works fine the HTML. otherwise the Page itself will go off track. And above all it is given within quotes, so no way that will mess up the page.

Comment: Yes, I actually know this, but there should be a reason. Did you follow my link? It all works there, any ideas why? What's different from your initial sample?

Comment: Yes , i followed the link , as like u say they are all working fine there. And even i tried with the name with that <> symbols it is also working fine i suppose.

Comment: Let me see whether i can change the href(div) into buttons

Comment: I created one more: http://jsfiddle.net/taPxL/, still working. No script changes!

Comment: This is all to show that the issue has actually nothing to do with `next()` function particularly, and javascript/jquery at all, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved it, Find the jquery below

```
  $(".quantity .subtract").click(function () {
        var qtyInput = $(this).nextAll('a');
        var qtytxt = $(qtyInput).prev('input');
        var qty = qtytxt.val();

        if (qty > 1)
            qtytxt.val(qty - 1);
        qtytxt.focus();
        return false;
    });
```

I simply got all next for the href and got the prev one , hence got the value of the TEXT as lik how i wanted.
Thanks to all u guys , Cheers ;)

Comment: consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the "tick" or "check" icon next to it